# Geth, how to revert back to certain EVM state/block

Tags: evm

I am trying to fuzz a smart contract on `Geth`, which involves contract state exploration. In order to explore a contract state `S1`, different contract functions with different inputs will be executed on the given state.

E.g., executing function `F1` on `S1` produces new state `S2`. How can I revert the contract state back to `S1`? In `Ganache CLI`, there are two custom management API, `evm_snapshop()` and `evm_revert()`, `evm_snapshot()` stores the evm snapshot and returns an `ID`, when `evm_revert()` is executed with the `ID`, the evm goes back to the snapshot state.

Is there anything similar to this in `Geth`? Or do I just have to start all over again by re-executing all the previous transactions to reproduce a contract state?

Comment: Geth used to have [`debug.setHead`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_sethead).